# Execute method on parent UiViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

From one `UIViewController` I call an another `UIViewController`

```
FullScreenViewController *anotherViewController = [[FullScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

[theWindow addSubview:newView];
```

On the opened `FullScreenViewController`, I want to put an `UIButton` to call a method inside the parent `UIViewController`.

There's a way to do that? How should I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a **unretained reference** to the child view controller during its construction (by passing in self in the parent), which the child could use to call methods on it's parent.

Better still you could make the parent a delegate of the child:
[How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)